# Recursion not working while traversing through the tree

Tags: python

I have a tree structure where at every node there is a list of documents (document length can vary from 5 to 500), and each document contains a number of words. I want to store in how many documents each word appears in the form of a dictionary.
For example: If the document at any node `A = [['b','m','n'],['b'],['g'],['o','b','g'],['b','g']]`
The count should be stored in each node like `A.occurlist = {'b':4,'m':1,'n':1,'g':3,'o':1`

I am running the below code but it is not able to incur recursion and showing error: **TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable**

Code:

```
def occurlist(node):
    wordSet = set()
    lis = []
    next_node = []
    child_nodes = node.children
    for child in child_nodes:
        next_node.append(child)
        lis += child.documents
    wordSet = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lis))
    occurDict = {word:0 for word in wordSet}
    for child in child_nodes:
        occurlist = {}
        occurlist.update(copy.deepcopy(occurDict))
        for doc in child.documents:
            for word in wordSet:
                if word in doc:
                    occurlist[word] +=1
        child.occurlist = occurlist
        print child.name
    print len(next_node)
    if next_node:
        for nn in next_node:
            if not nn.update:
                occurlist(nn)

occurlist(Savings_Accounts)
```

Savings_Accounts is the name of root node.

Comment: The bug is due to a name conflict: `occurlist` is both a dictionary (line 12) and a function (line 1). The dictionary masks the function.

Comment: Not clear: Is `A` the input to the `occurlist` function, i.e. `Savings_Accounts`, or is it just one node in that "tree", i.e.`child.documents`? Or is `A` itself the tree? If not, how does the tree itself look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the count of each element use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

A = [['b','m','n'],['b'],['g'],['o','b','g'],['b','g']]

dict(Counter([ele for sub in A for ele in set(sub)]))
#{'b': 4, 'm': 1, 'g': 3, 'o': 1, 'n': 1}
```

Comment: OP wants count in how many documents a word occurs, not total count of that word; probably convert each doc to a set first. `dict(Counter(ele for sub in A for ele in set(sub)))`

Comment: @tobias_k if you say so, I'll edit. Mostly followed input-output concept.

Comment: The example is not clear in this regard, but OP said so in the question.